# how to get the values of entity reference fields of a content type in a node page?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, entities

There is a content type in my website called `singer` and every singer may have `name` and some other information. there is another content type called `songs` and every song has two fields: (1) File (2) name. I also created an Entity Reference field in `songs` which links the song to a singer. obviously every singer may have any number of linked songs.

I listed the singers in a page and it must display every singer information and `songs` when the user click on any of the singers. this is my `template.tpl.php`

```
function MyThere_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
    if (isset($variables['node'])) 
   {
        switch ($variables['node']->type)
        {
        case "singer":
            $suggest = "page__node__singers";
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
            $variables['name'] = t($variables['node']->field_singer_name['und'][0]['value']);
            break;           
        }
    }
}
```

I can get value of `singer` fields (using `kpr()`) but I don't know how to get the value of `songs` fields that are linked to a singer.

thanks

Comment: Hello. Could you make a title of your question a bit more precise? Design questions are often closed as "primarily opinion based", and you seem to ask pretty decent one, just with misleading title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this thing

```
// $node represents the node object
// field_songs is the field used in content type to reference field. 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$songs = $wrapper->field_songs->value();
```

Now in `$songs` you will have each songs object and you can print what ever information you want to print from it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I searched a lot about this function , but I still don't know what `$node` should be. I tried `$variables['node']` but this is the current node and since fields of the `$songs` content type don't belong to the `$singer` it reported error. I guess `entity reference` field acts as an external key, so what should I assign to the `$node` variable? or more precisely how do I can get the relevant node of `songs` that is linked to `singer`?

Comment: Go through this link:

http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/how-use-entity-metadata-wrappers-drupal-7

Comment: this page didn't represent any thing about getting the `$node` variable.

Answer (score 1):

one approach is directly quering the referenced field table. e.g.:

```
function MyThere_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  if (isset($variables['node']))
  {
    switch ($variables['node']->type)
    {
      case "singer":
        $suggest = "page__node__singers";
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
        $variables['name'] = t($variables['node']->field_singer_name['und'][0]['value']);

        // I don't know what is your table's structure, correct ref.field table col names. Because they are wrong in my example:)
        $query = db_select('node', 'n')''
        $query->join('field_data_field_MY_REF_FIELD_NAME', 'fdfr',
          'n.nid = fdfr.field_MY_REF_FIELD_NAME_NID');
        $query->fields('n', array('nid'));
        $query->condition('n.nid', $variables['node']->nid, '=');
        $query->execute()->fetchCol();

        break;
    }
  }
}
```